# SAPUI5/OpenUI5: Event when sap.m.Select is clicked

Tags: drop-down-menu, sapui5

I would like to attach an event to the button at the end of the sap.m.Select control to call the backend for values displayed in the dropdown of that control. How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: By "button at the end" do you mean the last item in the collection? Or do you mean a sap.m.Button placed next to the select control? Also what kind of data are shown in the drop down? What is your scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this running example. Hope it gives you some hints. Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
</script>
<script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="MyController" displayBlock="true">
        <Select id="test_select" forceSelection="false" items="{
     path: '/ProductCollection',
     sorter: { path: 'ProductId' }
    }">
    <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{ProductId}" />
   </Select>
    </mvc:View>
</script>
<script>
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
        "use strict";
        sap.ui.define([
            "jquery.sap.global",
            "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
            "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
        ], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
            "use strict";
            return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                onInit: function() {
                    this.oModel = new JSONModel();

                    this.getView().setModel(this.oModel);
                    var that = this;
                    var oSelect = this.getView().byId("test_select");
                    oSelect.ontap = function(oEvent) {
                        if (!oSelect.isOpen()) {
                            oSelect.setBusy(true);
                            that.oModel.setData({});
                            var callBackend = function() {
                                that.simulateBackendData();
                                oSelect.setBusy(false);
                            }
                            setTimeout(callBackend, 3000);
                        }
                        sap.m.Select.prototype.ontap.apply(this, arguments);
                    };

                },

                simulateBackendData: function() {

                    var oData = {
                        "ProductCollection": [{
                                "ProductId": Math.random()
                            },
                            {
                                "ProductId": Math.random()
                            },
                            {
                                "ProductId": Math.random()
                            },
                            {
                                "ProductId": Math.random()
                            },
                        ]
                    };

                    this.oModel.setData(oData);
                }

            });
        });
        sap.ui.xmlview({
            viewContent: jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
        }).placeAt("content");
    });
</script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content" role="application">
</body>

</html>
```